# I am trying to print values on nodes of a binary tree in javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

I am trying to print the node values of a binary tree in javascript.  I created a node class and Binary Search Tree class as you can see in my code below.  I am trying to use post order traversal. I also have an insert array class that will insert an array into a tree.  When I try to call the printPostOrder function, the output on my terminal is undefined.  What am I doing wrong? Code below

```
class Node {
    constructor (data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
};

class BST {
    constructor(root){
        this.root = null
    }
    insert(data){
        var newNode = new Node(data);
        if (this.root == null)
            this.root = newNode;
        else {
            this.insertNode(this.root, newNode);
        }    
    }
    insertNode(node, newNode){
        if (newNode.data < node.data)
        {    
            if (node.left == null)
                node.left = newNode;    
            else
            {
                node = node.left;
                this.insertNode(node, newNode);
            }

        }    
        else if (newNode.data > node.data)
        {
            if (node.right == null)
                node.right = newNode;
            else
            {
                node = node.right;
                this.insertNode(node, newNode);
            }
        }
    }
    insertArray(arr) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            this.insert(arr[i]);
    
    }
    printPostOrder(node){
        if (node) 
        {    
            this.printPostOrder(node.left);
            this.printPostOrder(node.right)
            console.log(node.data);
        }    
    }
}

var tree = new BST();

tree.insertArray([1, 3, 6, 7, -3, 13, 9, -2, 4, 8, 1, -4, -8]);

tree.printPostOrder(tree);
```

Comment: You should print node, not tree: ```tree.printPostOrder(tree.root);```.

Comment: Thank you I am pretty new to classes and object oriented programming

Comment: You can refer to the class I have written, it contains all basic functions for a binary tree in javascript.
Class - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/binary-tree
Documentation - https://dsinjs.github.io/binary-tree